# Почему не работает querySelector?

Tags: javascript, html

Пытаюсь учить HTML + Javascript. Хочу разобраться в работе querySelector() и querySelectorAll(), но не один из примеров не работает. Объясните, пожалуйста, в чём дело.

Пробовал вот этот пример: https://jsfiddle.net/quqLxkzu/7/

```js
(function() {
  var z = document.querySelector(".a1"); //знакомим
  z.addEventListener("click", move); //по клику по элементу
  var leftPos = 0;

  function move() {
    setInterval(animate, 10);
  };

  function animate() {
    z.style.top = leftPos + "px";
    leftPos++;
  };
})();
```

```css
.a1 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: pink;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="a1"></div>
</body>
```

P.S. Все необходимые теги вроде ,  и т.д. я добавил.

Comment: При нажатии на блок, он едет вниз. Что именно у вас не получается?

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный Он почему-то в браузере выполняется, но когда я пытаюсь запустить на компьютере, то он не может найти элемент с помощью querySelector().

Comment: а браузер - не на компьютере?

Comment: В каком смысле на компьютере? Для работы `js` необходима среда, а `querySelector`, и тому подобные методы являются частью `DOM`.

Comment: @Igor На компьютере

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный Я просто создаю файлы с HTML, CSS и JS. Подключаю JS и CSS к HTML файлу, открываю HTML с помощью браузера и пытаюсь отладидь JS через него. А он мне сразу ошибки кидает

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ваш код вызывается до того, как создан элемент, который этот код пытается найти.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  var z = document.querySelector(".a1"); //знакомим
  z.addEventListener("click", move); //по клику по элементу
  var leftPos = 0;

  function move() {
    setInterval(animate, 10);
  };

  function animate() {
    z.style.top = leftPos + "px";
    leftPos++;
  };
});
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное и извините за такие глупые вопросы

Comment: Спасибо! Очень полезно